# Write multiple tables to bigquery by filtering

Tags: google-bigquery, transform, pipeline, apache-beam, tablerow

I am reading from a jdbc connection converting to tablerows and then uploading the data to bigquery with the following code.

The data I am expecting has multiple columns, one of them called "Phone number". If I want to store rows where this phone number is less than 8 digits long in a different table, remove them, and write both tables (one with invalid phone numbers and the other with the remaining data with correct phone numbers) to bigquery.
What method can I use after reading the jdbc data to do this?

```
  private static PipelineResult run(JdbcConverters.JdbcToBigQueryOptions options) {

    
    // Create the pipeline
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    /*
     * Steps: 1) Read records via JDBC and convert to TableRow via RowMapper
     *        2) Filter data
     *        3) Append TableRow to BigQuery via BigQueryIO
     */
    pipeline
        /*
         * Step 1: Read records via JDBC and convert to TableRow
         *         via {@link org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO.RowMapper}
         */
        .apply(
            "Read from JdbcIO",
            DynamicJdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                    DynamicJdbcIO.DynamicDataSourceConfiguration.create(
                            options.getDriverClassName(),
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getConnectionURL(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withUsername(
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getUsername(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withPassword(
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getPassword(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withDriverJars(options.getDriverJars())
                        .withConnectionProperties(options.getConnectionProperties()))
                .withQuery(options.getQuery())
                .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                .withRowMapper(JdbcConverters.getResultSetToTableRow()))

        .apply(
            "Write to BigQuery",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .withoutValidation()
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withCustomGcsTempLocation(options.getBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory())
                .to(options.getOutputTable())
                

    // Execute the pipeline and return the result.
    return pipeline.run();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Filter` transform: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/filter/